# HTML5 Range Slider Min and Max Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have an HTML5 slider within an ASP.NET MVC 5 application:

```
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0.00" max="100" value="0" step="5">
```

How can I get the max value from an Microsoft SQL Server table?

Do I need to use Jquery/Ajax for this to access a controller action to then get the value from the database?

I have looked on the internet for answers but have had no luck so far.

Comment: Yes, you can use ajax to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have specified the Max value in the declaration of the slider.

If you mean how you can get the value of the slider from the database then, you need to query from the server side and set the value returned using jquery's val method in the Ajax call of get type.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't access the database directly from the View (your HTML page), that is against the principle of the MVC architecture.

Besides the MVC architecture you can use other tiers, and use an ORM like Entity Framework to access the Database.

Please check the link for more information: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En

To learn ASP.Net MVC I would recommend you to read the book from Dino Esposito (Programming Microsoft ASP.NET MVC), get the latest edition.